# What else do i have to add to make this question open

Tags: discussion

This function works for smaller video files, but if the video is over 10 minutes it won't save the jpeg image. An error comes up as before trans.

[FFMPEG unable to take frame and save as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003561/ffmpeg-to-take-videosnap)

Comment: What you definitely don't do - is post it again... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016151/ffmpeg-to-get-video-snap

Comment: Frankly, this Meta question is just about as bad as the SO question. You can't just dump your problem on the table and expect someone to fix it for you. If you really want help, either here or there, you need to explain what you've tried, what the results were, and _specifically_ what you don't understand. A sentence about the problem you're having in your SO question doesn't constitute a valid question here on Meta. What have you done to try to get your question reopened?

Comment: Yeah well no one bothers to anwser and it got closed seriously Ive wasted time with this sort of stuff then anything. Only two people tried to help wit hthe question the rest only just critised becasue of the question. Josh have you used ffmpeg before

Answer (score 7):

1. You haven't tried anything. We won't fix every one of your problems for you.
2. It is unclear what you are even trying to do.
3. You haven't even posted the complete error/formatted it correctly.

The main problem is that you are basically dumping some code there and saying "fix it." You haven't told what you tried, what the problem is, what you are trying to do, etc. You never even said what the code is for!

Comment: All it is is getting a frame from a video and saving it as an image

Comment: @alex Then maybe you should put that in your question?

Comment: This is really frustrating becasue ive got this stupid bug.

Comment: @alex That doesn't magically make it a good question

Comment: Well Ive tried my hardest to fix the question up and how much more can i do.

Comment: @alex So apparently "trying your hardest" is changing a single word in the title.

Comment: Well Ive changed the question numerous times asked for help and formatting the question.

Comment: @alex The only other change you made is adding the error message, which should have been there in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/573/discussion-between-alex-and-doorknob)

Comment: Ive edited everything properly im sick of getting into samantics